# Adding Graphic Card Does not increase FPS

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

My System Specs:
i5-2.4-3.2
16 GB RAM
SSD attached
........................
Blender works fine but it lags a lot even 100 frames animation of default blender box takes an hour. FPS are at 3.5-4
In this anxiety i considered to attach a graphic card to my system i connected multiple cards with my system but FPS did not increase it remained same even when there is no animation. I connected GTX 1060 ^GB graphic card too but there was no difference in performance of blender, it still lags and gets held for simple Grass plane generation a lot.
I left graphic card there and did not buy thinking first i should know what is the problem which i am unable to understand.
So Please help me out understanding my problem. What is wrong with my setting. Please Note i had enabled graphic card from CUDa too.

Answer (score 0):

Low fps depends on the complexity of your seen. No matter how high specs your computer has, if your seen is complex, your playback speed may be low. You may need to divide your movie into smaller scenes.

I think Slow playback speed is a known issue of blender. You need to disable all subdiv surface modifiers, avoid high resolution simulations, ...etc.